# Add the installation prefix of "Protobuf" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I'm using CMake 3.14.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Protobuf" with any
  of the following names:

    ProtobufConfig.cmake
    protobuf-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Protobuf" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Protobuf_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Protobuf" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Do you have Protobuf installed? How have you installed it?

Comment: Yes I have installed protobuf-compiler